# Is it possible to run shell code from programming language A in a script that is programmed in language B?

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am sorry about the confusing title, but what I'm asking is this: Could you run shell code from C (or any other programming language) in a buffer overflow script that is programmed in Java (or any other programming language)?

Comment: Is this question anyhow related to information security ?

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer to your confusing question is "yes".

Buffer overflow attacks take a few steps.  There's the delivery phase (delivering the vulnerability), exploit injection (gaining control of the Instruction Pointer), executing the exploit (getting the Instruction Pointer to run the attacker's code), and shell code (the payload the attacker wants to run.)

Delivering the exploit is utterly trivial.  Attackers write the delivery code in whatever language they are proficient in.  It doesn't matter what language the delivery code is written in, because the language simply has to be able to deliver specific byte values into the buffer at the point of the overflow.  Different languages have different ways of expressing byte values.  Many attacks these days are delivered in URLs, which are text strings that are perfectly capable of specifying exact byte values.  I've seen an attack delivered inside a barcode, which is clever, but still trivial.

The exploit injection step almost always utilizes the victim machine's binary machine language to exploit the vulnerability.  The attacker finds a way to get specific bytes loaded into the buffer at the right point, such that when the function containing the buffer returns, it loads the attacker's bytes into the Instruction Pointer instead of the bytes that are supposed to be there.

Once the attacker has control of the Instruction Pointer, the IP has to be set to point to the exploitation code, and execute it.  This can be easy, this can be difficult, or this can be virtually impossible.  It's all a part of analyzing the vulnerabilities to create a successful exploit.  The goal here is to get the victim machine to launch the shell code.

Once the exploit launches the attacker's shell code, the rest is history.  The shell code is specific to the machine it's being run on.  Most often, it's also in binary machine instructions that are hand written in assembler, because the original buffer being attacked usually has size constraints.  A buffer overflow vulnerability doesn't automatically mean an infinitely sized buffer is available for the attacker to deliver a large payload of shell code all at once.

Once the shell code is running, the attacker has pwned the machine, and can control it however he wants.  To start out he'll often have the shell code expose a native command shell present on the victim machine.  That could be bash, a Windows Command shell, PowerShell.  Other possibilities include downloading and running a malware agent; allowing for remotely managed operations.  Common names for these infected machines are "bots" or a "zombies".  These run in a custom command and control language designed for operating thousands of machines in a botnet.  Once the shell code is running, the attacker is free to download more code to carry out his malicious commands.

Notice that all the exploit languages are completely unrelated to the language the attack was originally delivered in.